# PHP - call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, datetime-format

There are couple of questions already but those did not help much. Below is the code.

```
<?php
  $from_date='2017-01-14';
  $from_week=date("W",strtotime($from_date));
  $year=date("Y",strtotime($from_date));
  $currentweek = date("W");
  for($i=$from_week;$i<=$currentweek;$i++) {
      $result=getWeek($i,$year);
      echo "Week:".$i." Start date:".$result['start']." End
date:".$result['end']."<br>";
   }
  function getWeek($week, $year) {
    $dto = new DateTime();
  //ERROR HERE//$result['start'] = $dto->setISODate($year, $week, 0)->format('Y-m-d');
    $result['end'] = $dto->setISODate($year, $week, 6)->format('Y-m-d');
    return $result;
  }
?>
```

Works completely fine with online php editors. I use LAMP and PHP version 5.2.4
Should the PHP version cause any error on this? Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you for the inputs in advance.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, that should really just be an answer for easy points.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Point taken :-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, the PHP version matters.

If you [read the manual for `setISODate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php), it clearly states:

> Version: 5.3.0    Changed the return value on success from NULL to DateTime.

You should *really* upgrade your PHP version. 5.2.4 was release about [*ten years ago*](http://www.php.net/releases/#5.2.4) (30 Aug, 2007) and has been unsupported for a long time now